# JQuery foreach with not

Tags: jquery, foreach

I want to use jQuery for each with not rendering element how can I do that

```
$.each($('.single-price .price'), function(){...}
```

but not render this element

```
 $.not($('.single-price .special .price'), function(){...}
```

in only one for loop

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking, do you mean: `$('.single-price .price').not('.single-price .special .price').each(function() { ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select elements first, then pass them to `each`:

```
$('.single-price :not(.special .price) .price').each(function() {
    // ... your code here
})
```

Comment: How is this the correct answer?   given that it uses spaces, the html hierarchy in OPs code would be mean that `.special` is a parent of `.price` and so using `.not(.special)` would not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use .stop() in between .each();
$('.single-price .special .price').stop();